# Having trouble getting Joda-time to run on Android.

Tags: android, time, jodatime, dalvik

I'm learning Android and have need for dates/times. I was recommended Joda-time by a colleague, which seems to be exactly what I need to make progress. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble getting it to work.

I'm using intellij and this is Android 2.2.

Steps I took:

1. Download the Joda-time jar from the [website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).
2. Intellij > File > Project Structure > Attach Classes
3. Build

I then get this error:

> warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class was probably produced by a broken compiler.)

I have no idea where to go from here. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can safely ignore those warning.  I get those in my included library but it works as expected.

Comment: Agreed. It's only a problem if you use reflection on the Joda-Time classes.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not using reflection on the Joda-Time classes, you can ignore the error. You can fix the problem by building the Joda-Time sourcecode with a Java 1.5 compiler.